# Case insensitive search matching with sed?

Tags: bash, sed, case-insensitive

I'm trying to use SED to extract text from two words, such as "Account" and "Recognized", and I'd like that the searching be case insensitive. So I tried to use the I parameter, but receive this error message:

`cat Security.txt | sed -n "/Account/,/Recognized/pI" | sed -e '1d' -e '$d' 
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: extra characters after command`

Comment: Post the content of `security.txt`.

Comment: Security.txt can be written in english or italian, like these examples:

<code>cat EN_Security.txt | sed -n "/Account/,/Recognized/p" | head
    Account Activity

  * Checkpoint Flow Started

    Saturday, April 16, 2016 at 11:26am UTC+02
    :::

% cat EN_Security.txt | sed -n "/Account/,/Recognized/p" | tail
  * Session updated

    Wednesday, June 17, 2015 at 2:04pm UTC+02
    :::

    Recognized Machines</code>

Comment: <code> % cat IT-Sicurezza.txt | sed -n "/account/,/Recognized/p" | head 
    Attività account

  * Login

    Venerdì 25 settembre 2015 alle ore 17:55 UTC+02
    :::

 % cat IT-Sicurezza.txt | sed -n "/account/,/Recognized/p" | tail
  * Login

    Martedì 4 febbraio 2014 alle ore 20:28 UTC+01
    :::

    Recognized Machines</code>

Comment: add the example to question instead of comment where formatting is a mess

Comment: @user2965031 Why not copy paste the exact text here..

Comment: It's too long. They are log files.

Answer (score 6):

Avoid [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

`/pattern/I` is how to specify case-insensitive matching in `sed`

```
sed -n "/Account/I,/Recognized/Ip" Security.txt | sed -e '1d' -e '$d'
```

You can use single `sed` command to achieve the same:

```
sed -n '/account/I,/recognized/I{/account/I!{/recognized/I!p}}' Security.txt
```

Or `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /account/{f=1; next} /recognized/{f=0} f' Security.txt
```

**Reference:**

- [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Comment: It's very strange, the command sed -n "/account/I,/recognized/Ip" works on "EN-Security.txt" and doesn't work on "IT-Security.txt", even though both contain the sequence "Recognized Machines".

Comment: @user2965031 that doesn't help in anyway what your problem might be... check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sed -n "/Account/,/Recognized/Ip"
```

i.e. change the order to: `Ip` instead of `pI`

Comment: Security.txt file sometimes contains both italian sentences (e.g. "Attività account") that english sentences (e.g. "Account Activity" ), and the command that you've suggested, if it's syntactically corrected, it doesn't grab the difference between the words "account" and "Account".

Comment: it should be `/Account/I` as well

Comment: @user2965031 I just focused on the error, but yes, if both words have to be case insensitive then `/Account/I` should be used.

Answer (score -1):

You have [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) where you should've fed the file directly to `sed`. Below could be a way of doing it.

```
$ cat file.txt 
Some stuff Account sllslsljjs Security.
Another stuff account name and ffss security.
$ sed -nE 's/^.*account[[:blank:]]*(.*)[[:blank:]]*security.*$/\1/pI' file.txt
sllslsljjs 
name and ffss
```

The `[[:blank:]]*` is greedy and will strip the spaces before and after the required text. The `-E` option enables the use of extended regular expressions.