# Case Insensitivity with Sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am using this command to find and replace strings in files.

`find . -name "dog.*" -exec sed -i "s/dog/cat/Ig" {} +`

It works fine for exact case match, but I want it to be case insensitive. I used `I` but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I fix this? I simply want to be able to replace the strings using a simple one-liner. The name of the files are dog with different extensions and I want to replace all incidents of dog with cat regardless of case.

Update: I have tried both lowercase and uppercase `I` but still not working. I have also tried it with gsed.

I have just realized something that I wonder may be the root cause of this issue. The case where it is not doing the replacement is when my keyword is part of a string. It will replace all instances of dog but if there is something like `dog_food`, it will not do the replacement.

Comment: lowercase `i`, not uppercase `I`.

Comment: [Case-insensitive search and replace with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412945/608639), [Case insensitive search matching with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39178188/608639), [Using sed to delete a case insensitive matched line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2157288/608639), etc.

Comment: @Barmar `GNU sed` allows both `i` and `I` for substitution command and only `I` for filtering, for example: `printf 'Sea\nset\nsat\n' | sed -n '/se/Ip'` as `i` in this usecase would mean `insert` command and not case-insensitive

Comment: @sfr do you get different results for `echo 'dog Dog DoG' | sed 's/dog/cat/Ig'` and `echo 'dog Dog DoG' | sed 's/dog/cat/ig'` ? you have tagged it `linux` so I'm assuming you have `GNU sed` in which case you should get same output for these two commands

Comment: @Barmar That does not work either. I tried it with gsed as well, but no luck.

Comment: @Sundeep I did get the same results.

Comment: I've just updated the post with more details.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem with partial words. I just tried `echo 'Dog_food dog' | sed 's/dog/cat/ig'` using GNU sed 4.2.1 on Linux, the output was `cat_food cat`

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. It seems to work fine (without regard to the case of the expressions).

Comment: After going through the files manually, I realized there have been some typos by the people who published the files which is causing the issue. Overall, it now works fine.